# Jquery modal gets disabled on windows resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a web page which displays jquery modal on button click.

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").modal();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="model" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="form-control-label">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" required id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]*" placeholder="John"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I resize the screen i.e, change width of the screen beyond certain limit, modal gets disabled. Is it the default behaviour of jquery modals and how to overcome this.?

Comment: add your code so we can debug the issue

Comment: code added. check whether you can debug.

Comment: actually this won't help, I can get this code from [Bootstrap Official Site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) but when I said I want to debug, I meant to check if there is something affecting on your modal because what happening with you is not a _default behaviour of jquery modals_ as you mentioned

Comment: done. code added.

Comment: this is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alaa_Mh/um7uh2xv/) just exactly the same as your code (I just added the button to call the modal) and it's working perfect on mobile, as I mentioned before, maybe there is something else affecting your code because of that I asked for your whole code or if you can make it in a fiddle, regardless, are you sure you are calling Jquery and bootstrap correctly ? (Jquery must be at the top and call bootstrab below it)